# Getting value of checkbox from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm really stuck here & I think I'm missing something really obvious. Kindly help me out(I'm a beginner in html,javascript)

I have made a `dropdown` containing a **un-ordered list** of items that I'm getting populated from `JSON`.Here'e the code for populating the list:

```
    var oldJSON = null;
    setTimeout(function main_func() { 
            var counter=0;
            $.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data) { 
                    if(JSON.stringify(oldJSON) != JSON.stringify(data)){ 
                        //$(".dropdown").html("");
                        //$("#notifications").append("<option style=display:none></option>")
                        $.each(data.items, function(i, v) {
                                counter++;  
                                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=counter ;
                                $('.dropdown').append('<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+counter+'"id="'+ counter +'"><label for="'+ counter +'"><div id="type">' + v.type +'</div>'+'<div id="text">' +v.text +'</div>'+'<div id="pnr">'+v.pnr+'</div>'+ '</label></li>');
                                ;});
                    }
                    oldJSON = data;
            });
            setTimeout(main_func,2000); 
    });
```

Now,my dropdown(consider it a facebook type notification) contains checkbox(for *mark as read*-haven't implemented it yet). I need to get the values from the checkbox. Right now I'm getting blank values. Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Here's my html:

```
<div id="selected_item"></div>
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper-demo">
        <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-4">
            <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main_func"></div>
        <div id="test"></div>
    ​</div> 
</section>
```

& here's the javascript to go along with it(which is not working):

```
$('.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    var title = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ","; 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.selected_item').append(title);
    } 
});
```

Kindly do edit the question if you can frame it better ;) . If its any help,I've pasted my code here for [html](http://pastebin.com/5pYLrZNE) [css](http://pastebin.com/yKqwjd8q) [json](http://pastebin.com/vS5EVz3k)

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: `var title = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val()` seems to be a redundant piece of code

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit: i haven't worked on jsfiddle that much yet. i can provide the whole code though?

Comment: @Vandesh: like i said,I'm new to all this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Please click here and play with it

Comment: actually i' trying it...i just don't know how to use my JSON file here

Comment: could you post the HTML of after the checkbox added state?

Comment: when you click on checkbox, do you want put in selected_item only the checkbox that you clicked or all checked?

Comment: @user3401335: i want all checked items so that i can reset the my _counter_ for new messages from JSON.

Comment: @Vandesh: i added the code for populating the list. is that what you wanted?

Comment: i have added the whole code in the question if you need it ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4t3g5/)

```
$('.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    var title = "";
    $('.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){           
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if(title != "")
            title = title + ',';

        title = title + $(this).val();            
    } 
    $('#selected_item').html(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your demo is working exactly like i wanted. Thanks for that but in my code,on selecting checkbox,its not printing anything. I know i'm missing something **really obvious** here,but could you please help me out? I have added my whole code in the question if you need to see it

Comment: 1.at the end of second line, there is "," instead ";"
2.the selector for 'selected_item' must be "#" selected_item because "#" is the selector for id, and "." for attribute class
that for work. but append don't work if you uncheck a checkbox. 
then every time you check or uncheck a checkbox, the list must be rebuild.

Comment: yes i have already implemented your code...even after that its not printing anything

Comment: make a fiddle with your javascript and html

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alok24/qxa89/) is the jsfiddle(i dont know how to get my JSON file into it,sorry)

Comment: I have simplified the code because we cannot use ajax on fiddle.
when you write html put a space between id and value in input checkbox
in css .wrapper-dropdown-4 .dropdown i have delete opacity: 0 and pointer-events: none; that show the list and permit the click on checkbox
the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Ubs6/1/

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not being able to understand you but i compared the 2 css files(my previous one & your new one) & the only difference was that you deleted `opacity` & `pointer-events` & some commented code. I didn't see any spacing issue between `id` & `value`

Comment: i know it must be getting quite irritating for you but please kindly bear with me. I'm new to html,css & javascript

Comment: in fiddle add jquery(dropdownllist on the left). try to delete some js code in your example for check if ther's another problem